# What is the correct order of requiring and mocking files using Jest?

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, integration-testing, supertest

I'm trying to create an integration test using Jest for my Express app. I think I have a conceptual misunderstanding as my tests are behaving strangely. My goal is to test the following scenario. I'm hitting a specific endpoint using Supertest, and I want to check whether an error handler middleware is called if there is a mocked error. I want to check whether the error handler is not called, if there is no error present. I have the following test file:

test.js

```
const request = require('supertest')

describe('Error handler', () => {
  let server
  let router

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
    jest.resetAllMocks()
  })

  afterEach(async () => {
    await server.close()
  })

  it('should be triggered if there is a router error', async () => {  
    jest.mock('../../routes/')
    router = require('../../routes/')
  
    router.mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error()
    })
  
    server = require('../../server')

    const res = await request(server)
      .get('')
      .expect(500)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  
    expect(res.body.error).toBe('Error')
    expect(res.body.message).toBe('Something went wrong!')
    expect(res.body.status).toBe(500 )  
  })

  it('should not be triggered if there is no router error', async () => {  
    server = require('../../server')
    
    const res = await request(server)
      .get('')
      .expect(201)
      .expect('Content-Type', /text/)
  })

})
```

What I think is happening is the following. Before each test I reset all modules, because I don't want to have the cached version of my server from the first require, I want to overwrite it. I also reset all mocks, so when the second test runs, no mock is used, no fake error is forced, so the middleware is not called and I'm getting back a vanilla 200 result.

After this is done, I start testing the scenario when there is an error. I mock the routes file that exports my routes so I can force a fake error. Then I require the server, this way, I suppose, it's loading the server up with the fake, error throwing route. Then I wait for the response with Supertest, and assert that I indeed got an error back - hence the error handler middleware has been triggered and worked.

The afterEach hook is called, the server is closed, then the beforeEach hook initializes everything, again. Now I have my vanilla implementation without the mock. I require my server, hit the homepage with a get request, and I get back the correct response.

The strange thing is that for some reason the second test seems to not exit gracefully. If I change my implementation from async - await in the second test, to specify the done callback, and then if I call it at the end of the test, it seems to be working.

I tried a lot of possible permutations, including putting the mocking part to the beforeEach hook, starting the server before / after mocking, and I got weird results. I feel like I have conceptual misunderstandings, but I don't know where, because there are so many moving parts.

Any help to make me understand what is wrong would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**

I thought that most parts can be considered a black box, but now I realize that the fact that I'm trying to create an app using Socket.IO makes the setup process a bit more convoluted.

I don't want Express to automatically create a server for me, because I want to use socketIO. So for now I only create a function with the appropiate signature, and that is 'app'. This can be given as an argument to http.Server(). I configure it with options and the middlewares that I want to use. I do not want to call app.listen, because that way Socket.IO could not do its own thing.

config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const indexRouter = require('./routes/')
const errorHandler = require('./middlewares/express/errorHandler')

const app = express()

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '/views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('', indexRouter)
app.use(errorHandler)

module.exports = app
```

In server.js I require this app, and then I create a HTTP server using it. After that, I feed it to 'socket.io', so it is connected to the proper instance. In server.js I do not call server.listen, I want to export it to a file that actually starts up the server (index.js) and I want to export it to my tests, so Supertest can spin it up.

server.js

```
// App is an Express server set up to use specific middlewares
const app = require('./config')
// Create a server instance so it can be used by to SocketIO
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const logger = require('./utils/logger')
const Game = require('./service/game')
const game = new Game()

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  logger.info(`There is a new connection! Socket ID: ${socket.id}`)
  
  // If this is the first connection in the game, start the clock
  if (!game.clockStarted) {
    game.startClock(io)
    game.clockStarted = true
  }
  
  game.addPlayer(socket)
  
  socket.on('increaseTime', game.increaseTime.bind(game))
})

module.exports = server
```

If I understand everything correctly, basically the same thing happens, expect for a few additional steps in the example that you provided. There is no need to start the server, and then use Supertest on it, Supertest handles the process of starting up the server when I use request(server).get, etc.

**EDIT 2**

Right now I'm not sure whether mocking like that is enough. Some mysterious things leaves the Supertest requests hanging, and it might be that somewhere along the way it can not be ended, although I do not see why would that be the case. Anyway, here is the router:

routes/index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.status(200).render('../views/')
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})

router.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.status(404).render('../views/not-found')
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }  
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: The order looks ok. resetAllMocks is awful, use restoreAllMocks, but not a problem here. *the second test seems to not exit gracefully* - what does happen? *to specify the done callback, and then if I call it at the end of the test, it seems to be working.* - what exactly did you try? `await server.close()` - this is a mistake, `close` is asynchronous but it's callback-based and doesn't return a promise, not sure if this contributes to the problem but it can. Try `server.close(done)`. If this solves the issue then that's it.

Comment: @EstusFlask if I leave the implementation as is, I got an error at the second test saying "an async callback was not invoked within 5000ms" and "A worker prrocess has failed to execute gracefully". So I suppose somehow the second test is not told that it is supposed to be finished. What is strange that if I change the async - await there to a vanilla callback, it seems like it does. I don't get how that could make a difference as this guide (https://www.albertgao.xyz/2017/05/24/how-to-test-expressjs-with-jest-and-supertest/) linked by jest docs says they can be used interchangeably

Comment: I suppose what I dont get is that -at least for me- it seems like Supertest, and Jest both should be told that they are done, so the execution can continue in the right order. If I use server.close(done) as you told me, the first test fails with an error that the server is not running. So I guess some operations are not executed in the correct order, the server gets closed before anything else could happen - but how that can happen is a mystery for me.

Anyway, I'm lost, bot a bit less lost, so thank you for your help. I had know idea whether anything I implemented was right before

Comment: Please, update `...` with real code. If there's `server.listen` in server.js then it needs `close` in `afterEach` -  but also needs to wait for `listening` event before doing `request`. Also Supertest can use Express instance and handle a server itself, see https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest#example , this would make the whole thing less complicated.  That you get this error with async/await likely means that Supertest stalled for some reason, like server setup failed because a port wasn't available. If you don't have `error` event listeners this makes debugging more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of requiring and mocking is correct but the order of setting up and shutting down a server probably isn't.

A safe way is to make sure the server is available before doing requests. Since Node `http` is asynchronous and callback-based, errors cannot be expected to be handled in `async` functions without promisification. Considering that `server.listen(...)` was called in server.js, it can be:

```
...
server = require('../../server')
expect(server.listening).toBe(true);
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  server.once('listening', resolve).once('error', reject);
});
const res = await request(server)
...
```

`close` is asynchronous and doesn't return a promise so there's nothing to `await`. Since it's in a dedicated block, a short way is to use `done` callback:

```
afterEach(done => {
  server.close(done)
})
```

In case errors are suppressed in `error` listener, `server.on('error', console.error)` can make troubleshooting easier.

Supertest can handle server creation itself:

> You may pass an http.Server, or a Function to request() - if the server is not already listening for connections then it is bound to an ephemeral port for you so there is no need to keep track of ports.

And can be provided with Express instance instead of Node server, this eliminates the need to handle server instances manually:

```
await request(app)
...
```

Comment: I edited the question. This is my first time using Socket.IO and writing integration tests, so there are a lot of new things for me to digest. I will be trying to fix things with the things that you corrected. You already helped me by showing where I'm NOT totally lost here